# unique_ptr is copying when raw pointer is passed into its constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I am trying to understand how unique pointers work in modern C++.

When I went through the documentations (cppreference and others), I was able to understand that `unique_ptr` will transfer ownership and not share it. But I am not able to understand why `unique_ptr` is acting strange when working with a raw pointer passed into its constructor.

For example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class foo{
    int x;
public:
    foo(): x(0) {}
    foo(int a): x(a) {}
    foo(const foo& f): x(f.x) {}
};

int main(){
    foo *ptr = new foo(5);
    std::unique_ptr<foo> uptr(ptr);
    std::cout << ptr << "\n";
    std::cout << uptr.get() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Output below:

```
0x5c7bc80
0x5c7bc80
```

Queries:

- Is the raw pointer being passed into the copy constructor? Isn't the copy constructor deleted (`=delete`)? Why is the raw pointer printing the same address as `unique_ptr`?
- Is this a design flaw of `unique_ptr`?
- How do I overcome this issue?
- What is the use of `std::make_unique()`? I tried changing the line `std::unique_ptr<foo> uptr(ptr);` to `std::unique_ptr<foo> uptr(std::make_unique<foo>(*ptr));` but nothing changed.

Comment: What do you find strange about unique_ptr in your code and why ?

Comment: `unique_ptr` transfers ownership, but raw pointers... they are too stupid. They do NOT transfer.

Comment: why not use : std::unique_ptr<foo> uptr = std::make_unique<foo>(5);

new and delete are no more required with std::unique_ptr.

Comment: The constructor called here is not the copy constructor. A copy constructor would accept the same type (`unique_ptr<foo>`), but your construtor accepts `foo *`.

Comment: *"I tried ... `make_unique` but nothing changed"* I don't believe you, you should've got different addresses. The primary use of `make_unique` is to able to not think where `new` is or isn't safe to use, by not using it at all and using `make_unique` instead.

Comment: The fundamental error is that it's not the copy constructor. A copy constructor would be passing a `unique_ptr<foo>` to the constructor, not a raw pointer.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I have added image for you reference :)

Comment: Don't post images of code! And also you call `uptr.get()` instead of `uptr1.get()` in your screenshotted snippet, printing the address of the wrong pointer

Comment: You're not printing the pointer created with `make_unique`.

Comment: @Pisers `unique_ptr` won't share ownership, but raw pointers do not express ownership. You can point to a character in a string with a raw pointer without becoming the owner of that character. In the same way you can point to an object with a raw pointer without taking ownership. So a `unique_ptr` and a raw pointer can easily point to the same thing, but only the `unique_ptr` owns it. If you try to express ownership with the raw pointer, such as by using it with `delete` then you've made a mistake.

Comment: No copy constructor is called in your code. The constructor of `std::unique_ptr` taking a raw pointer takes ownership of an existing object an nothing more; no new object is created. As for the last point: I'm pretty sure you did something wrong in your test there; this should work: https://godbolt.org/z/ebWzo3baq

Comment: Omg!! Missed it!! I tried uptr1.get() and it printed a different address

Comment: https://youtu.be/JfmTagWcqoE

Comment: How do I overcome this issue?? Is never using raw pointers with unique_ptr, the only solution??

Comment: What issue are you talking about?

Comment: @Pisers I don't understand what the issue is. Clearly you are expecting some behaviour from unique_ptr which is not correct.

Comment: Both of them have access to the memory location, right??

Comment: @Pisers No completely different memory locations. You clearly have a fundamental misunderstand here.

Comment: @Pisers unique_ptr is not a unique object across the whole program, it's **unique ownership** of a particular object. It's about  **who deletes the object**.

Comment: Line no. 13 and 14 printing the same address is what I want to avoid :(

Comment: @Pisers That's not how unique_ptr works. It takes ownership of the raw pointer passed to it.

Comment: unique_ptr is not about access control, it is about ownership. It is common to use `unique_ptr` to manage object lifetime and ownership, and use multiple raw pointers to *observe* and access same object.

Comment: @Pisers You have something in your head, you could probably code it for yourself, but you are just looking in the wrong place when you look at `unique_ptr`.

Comment: @Pisers I don't see an issue with this, it's a perfectly legal usecase. You just need to be sure to not use the raw pointer after the `unique_ptr` dies.

Comment: It is valid, but playing mix-n-match like this with raw and smart pointers leads to much wailing and gnashing of teeth, effectively throwing you back in to the old world of pure raw pointers. Sometimes you have to do it because you do not want to transfer ownership when passing a pointer into an API that expects a non-owning pointer, but keep it short and controlled and don't do anything stupid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is the raw pointer being passed into the copy constructor?

Not the **copy** constructor, no (that takes another `unique_ptr` as input).  The raw pointer is being passed to a **converting** constructor instead, specifically this one in this case:

```cpp
explicit unique_ptr( pointer p ) noexcept;
```

> Isn't the copy constructor deleted (`=delete`)?

Yes.  But this code is not invoking the copy constructor.

> Why is the raw pointer printing the same address as the `unique_ptr`?

Because the `unique_ptr` is simply copying the input pointer as-is into its own internal member pointer, taking ownership of the *object* that is being pointed at. You are printing the value of the two pointers, and they have the same value because they are pointing at the same object in memory.

> Is this a design flaw of `unique_ptr`?

No.

> How do I overcome this issue?

What issue?  There is no issue here.  The `unique_ptr` is acting as designed.

> What is the use of `std::make_unique()`?

To more efficiently allocate memory, construct an object in that memory, and take ownership of that memory with a new `unique_ptr`, all in one operation.

> I tried changing the line `std::unique_ptr<foo> uptr(ptr);` to `std::unique_ptr<foo> uptr(std::make_unique<foo>(*ptr));` but nothing changed.

It should have.

The expression `std::make_unique<foo>(*ptr)` is creating a new `foo` object that is separate from the object that `ptr` is pointing at.  It will pass the dereferenced `*ptr` object to the new `foo` object's copy constructor.

And then, in the expression `std::unique_ptr<foo> uptr(...);`, `uptr` is moving the `unique_ptr` that `make_unique()` returns, which is pointing at the new `foo` object.  So `uptr` now owns that `foo` object.

Subsequently, your 2 prints should be outputting different values, since `ptr` and `uptr` are pointing at different `foo` objects.

Note that in this situation, you would be leaking the `foo` object that `ptr` is pointing at, since no `unique_ptr` is taking ownership of that object.  So you are responsible for `delete`'ing it manually.

This code:

```cpp
foo *ptr = new foo(5);
std::unique_ptr<foo> uptr(ptr);
```

Can be changed to this instead:

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<foo> uptr = std::make_unique<foo>(5);
```

or:

```cpp
auto uptr = std::make_unique<foo>(5);
```

`std::make_unique()` allocates and constructs the type specified in its template argument, passing the input parameters to that object's constructor.